# JavaScript document observe

Tags: javascript

I would like to write my own document observe function. I've read that the following is normally used:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function () {
    console.log('wiee');
});
```

This however isn't working in IE9 for example. So I'd like to write my own custom one. I can't find any info on it as 99% of all programmers always point to libraries.

I want a pure JavaScript answer, no 3rd party libraries.

Comment: `I'd like to write my own custom one` - What have you tried so far? What's the problem?

Comment: Did you do a Google search for "javascript on dom loaded"? If so you'd know that you can use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)

Comment: Where did you hear about `document.observe('dom:loaded'`? I haven't heard of it. Does it work on any browser?

Comment: @JuanMendes [`document.observe` is a Prototype.js method](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks, I didn't know people still used Prototype, specially if it's modifying native objects, yuck. I guess at least it isn't modifying existing properties...

Answer (score 2):

The event you appear to be looking for is document load event.

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("All resources finished loading!");
});
```

This will wait for all external content to load, if you're not interested in waiting, the `DOMContentLoaded` event can be used instead

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM Parsed");
});
```

Comment: That will wait for images and other resources, the OP is looking for `dom:loaded`

Comment: @JuanMendes - thanks, yes you're right. Answer updated

Comment: And if the OP needs support for IE < 9, the easiest way is to just put your script just before the closing body tag